# ASP.NET MVC 5 Forms Authentication using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Forms auth and AD membership provider as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" 
             enableSearchMethods="true" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

I have Anonymous Auth **Enabled**, and Windows Auth **Disabled**.

I can successfully authenticate against AD, and the value of `User.Identity.Name` indeed shows my username. However `IsAuthenticated` is false. Why?

I'd like to use some flag in my layout to show/hide navigation. Right now, I'm resorting to this in my view:

`@if (@User.Identity.Name == "") { show insecure content }`

I am using my own `Login` method as defined in my `AccountController` as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Login model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {             
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            _logger.Info("AccountController.Login() User.Identity.Name=" + User.Identity.Name);
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username and/or password");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I'm also not entirely convinced that the following methods are working as expected in my /Logout:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
Session.Abandon();
```

Perhaps I'm not entirely understanding the expected behavior of `User.Identity` when using `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

Comment: Does MVC5 require you to set an auth cookie?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the scaffolded MVC5 application there is a section for `SignInAsync` where you must set the claims identity for authentication.  I had to make some changes to mine but it will look like this:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName), }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
        }
```

I had run into the same issue and followed this post along with some others to resolve it: http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html

I was told in a previous post that MVC5 did away with form auth in favor of claims, I may be wrong and perhaps some one can shed more light on that.

Comment: I rolled my own Login method using Membership.ValidateUser. Updated question with that code.